# React context not working even though it has been imported. 'X is declared but it's value is never read'

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to render questions for a quiz-app I'm creating. I have the questions in an array in a separate data.js file at the project root.

I have a quiz.js file in src/contexts/:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import questions from "../data";

const initialState = {
  currentQuestionIndex: 0,
  questions,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "NEXT_QUESTION") {
    return {
      ...state,
      currentQuestionIndex: state.currentQuestionIndex + 1,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export const QuizContext = createContext();

export const QuizProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const value = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log("state", value);
  return <QuizContext.Provider value={value}>{children</QuizContext.Provider>;
};
```

And my Question.js file in src/components/:

```
import Answer from "./Answer";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { QuizContext } from "../contexts/quiz";

const Question = ({ questions }) => {
  const [quizState] = useContext(QuizContext);
  console.log("Question", quizState);
  const currentQuestion = quizState.questions[quizState.currentQuestionIndex];
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="question">{currentQuestion.question}</div>
      <div className="answers">
        <Answer />
        <Answer />
        <Answer />
        <Answer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Question;
```

In my Question.js file the 'questions' value is greyed out in VS Code because it's not being read but I don't understand how it isn't.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Reason for the graying out the "questions" is you are not using it. you are using questions from context but not what you are getting from props.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of Context is that you do not have to pass props manually. And hence you are not reading them.

```
const Question = ({ questions }) => {
```

But you are trying to destructure your props here and expecting a `questions` prop. This will not be coming and the correct way to read is using `useContext` as you have done in the rest of the code.